# Trigger Pipeline on any Pull Request from any branch and feature branches

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I have pipeline for some backend app for example, I would like to create trigger that run the pipeline whenever a pull request is created (before the approve and merge) but not only for the main/master branch, also for any branches

For example if I create a pull request from branch side branch "abc" to side branch "xyz" the pipeline will be triggered and run.

Also if in the feature I will create branch with the name "foobar" and create pull request to some other side branch the pipeline will be created.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: are yourmrepos in azure devops or github ?

Comment: in azure devops

Comment: Hi ITBYD, any update on this question, have you checked my answer, does my answer answered your question?

Answer (score 2):

In the DevOps git repo, PR syntax is invalid.

The only way you can trigger the pipeline via PR in DevOps is through branch settings.

**1, Go to branch settings.**

[image]

[image]

2, Add a build validation policy for all of the branches.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `pr` triggers. You can include which branches do you want to trigger a build. In the below example when you create a pull request **for** current branch the pipeline will run. You can also use regex syntax like `feature/*`

```
trigger:
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - current
    - xyz
    exclude:
      - uat
```

https://blog.geralexgr.com/devops/build-triggers-on-azure-devops-pipelines

Comment: Worth noting that this doesn't work if the repos are hosted in Azure Repos. If they are hosted in Azure Repos you would have to use build validation in the branch policies (but would be very fiddly for what OP wants)